# Illustrator file to colorable/fillable SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, draw

At the moment i am working on a coloring page for a client. Another agency send me Illustrator file which contains a drawing in black and white. Creating the possibility to 'draw' in different colors is not so hard using a bit of javascript (jQuery) and canvas.

However, i am also looking for something to create a "bucket"-tool (to fill in whole areas with a specific color). I guess i could use the vector file to create a SVG file and the create a javascript function to fill in a clicked area of the SVG with the selected color - but i am afraid the illustration is not up to par because some lines are not connected in the 'right way'.

Is there a way to fill in a image (or SVG) with a certain color, but *between the lines*? And if not; does anybody know a something similar which gives the same result?

I hope my questions is clear (considering my English isn't perfect).
Your help is much appreciated!

~ Frank

Answer (score 0):

With SVG, you can really only apply the `fill` property to actual shapes. If the region that you wish to "color" isn't a shape, then you'll have to create one to apply the fill. If you're only using 100% opacity, then (depending on the specific graphic) it may be easy to create a dummy rectangle and place it behind the other shapes. You could then fill this rectangle. (Note: SVG doesn't support `z-index`, so to place the rectangle "behind" other shapes you'll have to insert it before those other shapes in the document.)

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts Stephen! Good one on the z-index also.

Answer (score 0):

To use pure SVG, you will need to ensure it consists of connected shapes (as you have discovered).

If you can't arrange for your illustrations to be created that way, then a possible solution is to render the SVG to a canvas and you old-fashioned "flood" fills to fill your shapes.  Examples of how to do the rendering to canvas can be found in other questions here.  Flood fills are an easy technique which you should not have trouble finding example code for.

Comment: Paul, "flood" is a most good keyword!  I'm going to look into it. Thanks! Could you maybe share some links to articles on this subject?